# I wanted to reverse the animation in GSAP timeline

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I'm working on GSAP and I wanted to reverse the animation. I used the following approach, but it didn't work. Is there any syntactical error?

```
  const svg1 = document.querySelector(".svg1"); 
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const tl1 = gsap.timeline({
    onComplete: reverse(),
  });
  const tl2 = gsap.timeline();
  tl1.from(
    svg1,
    { rotate: "0deg,", scale: 1 },
    { rotate: "30deg", scale: 0.8, duration: 2 }
  );
  function reverse() {
    tl2.from(
      svg1,
      { rotate: "30deg,", scale: 0.8 },
      { rotate: "0deg", scale: 1, duration: 2 }
    );
    tl1.play();
  }
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Does the animation play but not as expected? Does it not play at all? Can you provide us with an example that shows the problem?

Comment: It doesn't play at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid tween. You should either pass in one vars parameter and use `.to()` or use two vars parameters and use `.fromTo()`.

To get it to repeat, just use the `repeat` and `yoyo` attributes!

```
const tl1 = gsap.timeline({ repeat: 1, yoyo: true });
tl1.from(".svg1", { rotate: 30, scale: 0.8, duration: 2 });
```

I highly recommend the [GSAP Getting Started article](https://greensock.com/get-started/).

Comment: FYI the [GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) will get you faster answers to questions like these.